# Increase PHP Script Execution Time

Tags: php

I want to send hundreds of emails using PHP. To increase the execution time, I used **ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);** but after sending just **30** emails the browser shows me a blank page and does not send all of the emails.

I also changed the limit to 300, 600 ..

Comment: Watch out for web server timeout, 'cos I'm guessing you're running this via a web request; and this type of task should really be executed CLI via a cron task

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your script.

*set_time_limit* sets the maximum execution time in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed (see [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)).

Comment: Thanks, glad that i know i should place it on first invoked script. Not the second one. Kindly explain why it have to be the first?