# php throw errors at random lines

Tags: php

PHP throw errors at random lines

error message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded
```

in code we don't have any setting, which sets execution time to one second. And this error occurs on completely random lines. sometimes on simple if statement, sometimes on db query. I can't find any pattern. 
Maybe someone had similar problem, and had resolved it ?

Comment: Check your `php.ini`, it probably has been set in there to 1 second.

Comment: Do you have long-running loops in your programs? Do you call out to external programs that might take time? Do you do *anything* that might take a long time (well obviously you *do* but you need to locate those places)? Perhaps your database access should happen in smaller steps, not fetching thousands or more rows at once?

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude I don't think OP wants to resolve that scripts take longer than 1 second to run, but just wants to remove the time limit.

Comment: yes, we have long-running parts in our code. And at most case they run successful, and take much more than 1 second. Problem, that I can't locate anywhere 1 second limit. And if I testing, script can run  300 seconds (this limit is set in php.ini). But still in logs we get some random errors, and page respond with 500 http code.

Comment: try ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: and check may be some where it is defined for 1 second

Answer (score 1):

> And this error occurs on completely random lines

It's normal: PHP starts executing code, then fails after one second. So it can be any line, because it does not execute at the same speed all the time (think about I/O, memory, processor load, etc.)

> Maybe someone had similar problem, and had resolved it ?

It's a common problem. If you want to fix it you can either:

- Find where is the actual `php.ini` file that is user by your server/cli, find the line about `max_execution-time` and change the value to something like 30. Then reload/restart your server.
- Or you can add a first line on the first included file with `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);` just after the `<?php` tag. If there is no included file, then add this at the beginning of all your files.

More information:

- [How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php)
- [Increase PHP Script Execution Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140258/increase-php-script-execution-time)
- [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: I checked max_execution_time setting, and I am sure that issue is not there. It happens not with every request.